# How to scroll all content in block with position sticky and top styles?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, responsive-design

As you can see header always is fixed and has position: fixed, siderbar has property top: 6rem and also styles for scrolling, but content doesn't scroll fully. How I fix it without changing header styles? I would like to stay the same what you see when run this snippet but with correct scroll.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000rem;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.sidebar-title {
  background: #999;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #f20;
  width: 20%;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 6rem;
  position: sticky;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 100vh;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="header">header</header>
  
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-title">SIDEBAR</div>
    <ul>
      <li>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</li>
      <li>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</li>
      <li>ccccccccccccccc</li>
      <li>dddddddddddddd</li>
      <li>eeeeeeeeeeeee</li>
      <li>fffffffffffffffffff</li>
      <li>ggggggggggggg</li>
      <li>hhhhhhhhhhh</li>
      <li>iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</li>
      <li>jjjjjjjjjjjjjj</li>
      <li>kkkkkkkkkkk</li>
      <li>llllllllllll</li>
      <li>mmmmmmmmmmmmm</li>
      <li>nnnnnnnnnnnnnnn</li>
      <li>oooooooooooooo</li>
      <li>pppppppppppp</li>
      <li>qqqqqqqqqqqqqqq</li>
      <li>rrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</li>
      <li>ssssssssss</li>
      <li>tttttttttttt</li>
      <li>1111</li>
      <li>2222</li>
      <li>3333</li>
      <li>4444</li>
      <li>5555</li>
      
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want all the text in the sidebar to scroll down all the way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}



.container {

}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  position:sticky;
}

.sidebar-title {
  background: #999;
  width: 100%;
  height:30px;
  position:relative;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #f20;
  width: 20%;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 6rem;
  position: static;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 100vh;  
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <header class="header">header</header>
  
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-title">SIDEBAR</div>
   <div> <ul>
      <li>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</li>
      <li>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</li>
      <li>ccccccccccccccc</li>
      <li>dddddddddddddd</li>
      <li>eeeeeeeeeeeee</li>
      <li>fffffffffffffffffff</li>
      <li>ggggggggggggg</li>
      <li>hhhhhhhhhhh</li>
      <li>iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</li>
      <li>jjjjjjjjjjjjjj</li>
      <li>kkkkkkkkkkk</li>
      <li>llllllllllll</li>
      <li>mmmmmmmmmmmmm</li>
      <li>nnnnnnnnnnnnnnn</li>
      <li>oooooooooooooo</li>
      <li>pppppppppppp</li>
      <li>qqqqqqqqqqqqqqq</li>
      <li>rrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</li>
      <li>ssssssssss</li>
      <li>tttttttttttt</li>
      <li>1111</li>
      <li>2222</li>
      <li>3333</li>
      <li>4444</li>
      <li>5555</li>
      
    </ul></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I changed it to auto. Your variant is working, but in case it has 2 or 3 items it has this margin-bottom and of course it shouldn't be visible. Can I fix it without js?

Comment: Its not using JS? That is CSS i have added. Not quite sure what you mean? Its does not have a visible margin it should just show all content. As long as you have the top set to 6rem you will need it and it will not affect how it looks even with 2-3 items in it

Comment: I mean when we have 2 items in ul (2 li elements) the height, for example, of this element 30px, but also in this case we have margin-bottom: 6rem and it makes container bigger.

Comment: It will work, try adding more elements to it!

Comment: try to delete almost all items LI and leave only 2 and you will see empty space below (6rem of margin-botton)

Comment: because container becomes bigger because of margin-bottom and you will see red background

Comment: But you had the sidebar set to 100%, do you just want it to fit the ul content?

Comment: yes, correct! I need to fit it to ul elments and add scroll when it has a lot of items and bigger than screen

Comment: So do you not want the red to be 100% on screen?

Comment: yes, it should depends only on height of list (ul content) and at the bottom of side bar should be small margin (8px for example).

Comment: makes no sense mate, yes you want it 100% but fit content of ul, it already does that, if you want it to fit just ul content is only a few li then that is`nt going to be 100%

Comment: so how I can make visible all elements LI when we have a lot of them? Because with margin-bottom it makes container bigger we have 2-3 elements

Comment: just looking now matey

Comment: check out answer, changed it

Comment: still doesn't work. In this case the beggining of content is under the header and there is no space between header and sidebar. just check code editor)

Comment: Check it now, with edited answer

Comment: but in this case you shold scroll the page and the scroll content, it's very strange for user

Comment: and the sidebar should be sticky, because main page can has different size, so when you scroll main page sidebar should be sticky and scrollable